# How do I move bulk emails from Microsoft Outlook inbox to a outlook inbox sub folder?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I need to move 600 pages of inbox emails into a single inbox sub folder and don't see a way to select multiple pages in one go. Any ideas?

Comment: So after highlighting one message and hitting "Ctrl-A" to Select All doesn't work? Which version of Outlook are you using?  Which OS?

Comment: Talking about "pages"... I think Wendy means OWA, not Outlook.

Comment: Microsoft Outlook is a program, but it doesn't paginate the inbox.  Most likely this is outlook.com or owa.  I find it hard to believe MS has not implemented a filter or select all in OWA and/or Outlook.com.  Competitors have it.

Answer (score 23):

You can't.

According to a Microsoft Representative (who by the way was very nice), in Outlook.com (the web version) you can not select an entire folder for the purposes of moving the emails to another folder. You can select all and toggle read or unread, but not move.

Our work around was to log into that email with the resident outlook program (not the web) and make the big move there. (we moved 12,000 emails to a specific folder) Then we went back to using the web version.
Sorry for the bad news.

Comment: Not sure why this was not upvoted or selected as the answer. This is entirely true and what we had to do also.

Comment: This is *not* true! All you have to do is sort by type. Outlook cannot move dissimilar items into the Inbox, but if you sort by all mail, calendar, etc, you can just drag-and-drop as many items as you like.

Comment: @ErocM The question is badly worded.  The answer may apply to the real question, but the answer does not apply to the question, as written.

If the OP is truly using MS Outlook (the program, not the website), this answer is 100% wrong.  Outlook will allow you to select all.  If OP needs to work with outlook.com, the answer may be better.  However, I disbelieve there's no way to 'select all' in Outlook.com when gmail has it.

Answer (score 9):

Create a filter rule that matches all the mails you need, set the action to move to folder, execute immediately and remove the rule afterwards.

OR if you can only filter based on what to keep in the inbox:

Set a rule that moves away all mails you want to keep to a temp folder, then one to move ALL mails to the subfolder, then move back the temp mails (possibly with modified rule 1)

Comment: This seemed to work but after "copying" about 900 messages, outlook crashed and now crashes each time I run it. The emails on IMAP are just headers and no message contents.

Answer (score 0):

For the desktop version of Outlook (2013 for mine) after clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> I simply right click and choose the `Move` menu option to move the entire folder into a different folder.

Comment: gave you +1 back.  The downvote person is assuming outlook.com.  Which is a poor assumption since the question is poorly written.

Comment: Does not work on desktop version either: ctrl+A only select what was loaded from server (limited to a few hundred emails), not all emails that match the request.

Comment: This does not work for more than 4000 messages.

Answer (score -3):

Ctrl-A to select everything.
Or select the first email. Scroll down to the last one and Shift-click on the last one to select the entire range from first to last.

As far as I know these have been the methods for every version of Outlook that ever existed.

Comment: This will only work for the current page of emails, not all emails in the folder. He's got 600 pages, so doing this process 600 times isn't really feasible.

Comment: As MathewBonig said, when you select all, it does not give you the option to move. When you try to drag them after high lighting them all, all are deselected except for the first one.

Comment: Outlook cannot do this for more than 4000 messages, therefore, not suitable for "bulk".